# How to remove auto focus on button inside angular material modal?

Tags: css, angular, dialog, angular-material, angular-cdk

When we place button inside angular material dialog it is auto focussing first button in that modal.

[Stackblitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-hy9xhd?file=app/dialog-overview-example-dialog.html)

Comment: you can add "tabIndex=-1" to each button

Answer (score 19):

You can add the `autofocus = false` properties to the dialog to disable the auto focus.

Example as below:

```
const dialogRef = this.dialog.open(DialogOverviewExampleDialog, {
   width: '250px',
   data: {name: this.name, animal: this.animal},
   autoFocus: false 
});
```

Comment: The word `autofocus` in the phrase`autofocus = false` should be `autoFocus`. The letter f should be capitalized.